# Pinned taskbar applications losing their icons on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I can't see some icons on the taskbar.

When I open some applications it works good but when I try to pin the application, it becomes a blank white sheet icon. However, only a few applications are causing this problem.

Inside my taskbar folder `C:\Users\Sasha\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` all icons are normal.

When I unpin an application with wrong icon it becomes normal.

This doesn't work for me:

```
sfc /scannow
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
chkdsk C: /f
```

Comment: You cannot pin whatever you wish to the Taskbar. Folder type shortcuts often do not work. What are you trying to pin?

Comment: Applications.It works well few days ago

Comment: Most applications have an option to Pin to Taskbar when you right click on the item and should work . DISM and SFC did not work, so now try a Windows 10 Repair Install. Use the Media Creation Link, second link, download and run in place. When the option comes up, select Keep Everything. Always good to have a backup of documents. 

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10